# ¿Cómo excluyo los directorios con un nombre determinado con "tar"?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, tar

Estoy haciendo un pequeño script que me comprima todo el contenido del directorio /var/www/html

Dentro tengo una estructura tal como esta

- /var/www/html/prod/**vendor**
- /var/www/html/pruebas/src/**vendor**

Es decir en todos los directorios tengo un directorio **vendor**

Lo que intento con el script es recorrer todo el directorio principal excluyendo todos los directorios que se llamen vendor, para ello hago lo siguiente

```
DIA=`date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M"`

cd /tmp
rm -fr copia/
mkdir copia
cd copia

export GZIP=-9
tar -czvf $DIA-deploys.tar.gz --anchored --exclude=vendor * /root/deploys /var/www/html
```

Pero por lo que veo me incluye el directorio "vendor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes excluir utilizando una expresión regular:

```
--exclude="*/vendor/*"
```

Puedes probar la expresión con `find`, pues si en uno funciona en el otro lo hará:

```
find . -type f -not -path "*/vendor/*"
```

Comment: Ya ví mi fallo , ahora publico mi solución. Gracias por la ayuda